# I got error in the colab google tool, How i can fix out this error?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

```
from keras.datasets import mnist(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
```

> File "", line 1
>       from keras.datasets import mnist(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
>                                       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You have written everything in a single line

Comment: First line should be `from keras.datasets import mnist`

Comment: Second line should be `(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()`